# How to fix Flutter project not being able to run after moving from another machine - Android Studio 3.6.3 MacOS

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Whenever I move a flutter project from one Macintosh to another or even within the same Macintosh, the flutter project complains in several ways. Dart not configured, no emulator/device to choose from and unable to run main.dart. Also sometimes cannot find runner. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After moving a project from another computer or even from another folder!

1: Enable dart Support (it will prompt you)
2: Run 'flutter pub get' in terminal in the project root directory (remove the quotes in terminal)
3: Go to Preferences->Language & Frameworks -> Flutter and set the flutter SDK path

If necessary, close and open project again in Android Studio.